# Missing IBM Websphere classes for SSO (com.ibm.jca.idtoken)

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on

I am trying to enable SSO on a WAS 8.5, which is installed on an AS400, and for this I need to use the following classes in java:

```
import com.ibm.eim.token.IdentityToken;
import com.ibm.jca.idtoken.ConnectionFactoryImpl;
import com.ibm.jca.idtoken.ConnectionSpecImpl;
import com.ibm.jca.idtoken.IdentityTokenFactory;
```

I found the package `com.ibm.eim` in `\QIBM\ProdData\OS400\security\eim` on the WAS server. However, I cannot find the package `com.ibm.jca.idtoken` in the file system nor on the IBM Knowledge Center website either. Where can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found it. It is here in a jar in a jar in a rar file :

**com.ibm.jca.idtoken**:

```
\QIBM\ProdData\OS400\security\eim\idTokenRA.rar\idTokenRA.jar\com\ibm\jca\idtoken\
```

**com.ibm.eim.token**:

```
\QIBM\ProdData\OS400\security\eim\idTokenRA.rar\idToken.jar\com\ibm\eim\token\
```